# Boot partition full: Move to encrypted partition

Tags: boot, partition, boot-loader, luks

Once the `/boot` partition is half-full with a single kernel you can't upgrade,

Resizing is painful when the other partition is encrypted,

*Solution*: Move `/boot` to the encrypted partition.

**Backstory**:
Linux Mint 17 upgraded to 20 won't allow the latest kernel to be installed; that was my dilemma. There's much written on resizing partitions—terror is induced for encrypted partitions! Fortunately there's an alternative.

Having rendered my system "unbootable," I decided to provide some guidance (*my answer appears below*), others will hopefully chim in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit largely belongs to [Guilhem Moulin](https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/encrypted-boot.html), I merely simplify. Superuser will be required repeatedly and you may prefer to run command `su` for a root shell (alternatively, proceed commands with `sudo` where necessary).

**Encrypted partition: `/dev/sda5`**

Running `fdisk -l` lists partitions, e.g.,

```
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 500117503 499615746 238.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 500117503 499615744 238.2G 83 Linux
```

My encrypted partition is `/dev/sda5`, yours may vary (and you'll need to replace `/dev/sda5` accordingly).

**Prerequisite: LUKS1**

Check you're using LUKS1 by checking command `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5` outputs

```
Version:        1
```

For version 2, downgrade before proceeding (see the original article).

**Prerequisite: GRUB2**

Check you're using GRUB2 by checking command `grub-install --version` outputs version 2 or above.

**Prerequisite: Keyboard layout**

Check your passphrase remains the same when you switch to US keyboard layout. Consider changing your passphrase (for one that remains the same), or set your passphrase using a US layout (not recommended), or refer to the original article for a further workaround.

**Moving `/boot`**

Remount `/boot` as read-only to avoid data modification during the move:

```
mount -oremount,ro /boot
```

Recursively copy to a temporary directory (on the encrypted partition):

```
cp -axT /boot /boot.tmp
```

Unmount `/boot` and remove the (empty) directory:

```
umount /boot
rmdir /boot
```

Relocate the temporary directory:

```
mv -T /boot.tmp /boot
```

**Update `/etc/fstab`**

Command `cat /etc/fstab` will output something akin to:

```
UUID=38e... /boot ext2 defaults
```

You need to comment out that line (I favour `vim`).

**Enable cryptomount in GRUB2**

Add `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` to `/etc/default/grub`, generate your GRUB configuration file,

```
 update-grub
```

and install,

```
 grub-install /dev/sda
```

**Probably a good time to test**

Now is probably a good time to test all is going well: Reboot. You should be prompted for your passphrase and (after a disturbing long delay) be dropped into a initramfs prompt. Enter the following command:

```
 cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt
```

replacing `sda5_crypt` with the first parameter output by `cat /etc/crypttab` (if you've gotten this far without having run that command, just use `sda5_crypt`, we can fix it later). Next issue command:

```
 exit
```

Your system should now be booting, if it isn't, recovery should be relatively easy—boot from a Live USB and uncomment the line in `/etc/fstab`. (It's incredibly useful to have a Live USB available at all times.)

**Boot performance degraded**

GRUB isn't optimised for crypto-related CPU instructions—unlocking the encrypted partition will take considerable longer than it did before.

*Optional*: You can tweak for performance by sacrificing resistance against brute-force attacks. It's easier for PBKDF than Argon2—PBKDF slows brute-force attacks by requiring multiple iterations, whereas Argon2 slows attacks with a further variable, hence, tweaking PBKDF is easier. Check how many iterations are currently used with command `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5`, e.g.,

```
 Key Slot 0: ENABLED
      Iterations:           1208036
```

To improve performance by roughly a factor of two (simultaneously reducing brute-force resistance by half), we can reduce the number of iterations by just over half with command `cryptsetup luksChangeKey --pbkdf-force-iterations 500000 /dev/sda5`

```
 Enter passphrase to be changed:
 Enter new passphrase:
 Verify passphrase:
```

Your existing passphrase can be reused. As far as I can tell, a new key is added: In addition to the above, command `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5` now outputs

```
 Key Slot 1: ENABLED
      Iterations:           500000
```

PBKDF will try all key slots sequentially, to speed things up, run command `cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase --verbose /dev/sda5`

```
 Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5: 
 Key slot 1 unlocked.
 Command successful.
```

With command `cat /etc/crypttab` you'll see something like

```
 sda5_crypt UUID=66f... none luks,discard
```

add `,key-slot=1` on the end (changing `1` to match whatever you found above). If you tested all is well and used something other than that first parameter `sda5_crypt`, reboot and enter `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt` followed by `exit`, before the next step. Run command

```
 update-initramfs -u -k all
```

to generate and update your initramfs image. (Strictly speaking `-k all` isn't required, assuming you're following these instructions because you have a single kernel.)

**Update `/etc/fstab`**

Command `lsblk -o name,uuid` outputs

```
 NAME                  UUID
 sda                   
 ├─sda1                38e...
 ├─sda2                
 └─sda5                66f...
   └─sda5_crypt        B6U...
     ├─mint--vg-root   54f...
     └─mint--vg-swap_1 fe3...
```

To make your system bootable, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`

```
 UUID=54f... / ext4 defaults 0 1
```

run command `update-grub` followed by `grub-install /dev/sda`, and reboot.

***Hopefully you'll now have a bootable system.***

You'll need to enter your passphrase twice, which is unfortunate. Apparently there's a workaround (see the original article). I followed that entire article in one hit, ran into trouble, couldn't boot (prior to discovering `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt`). With the above instructions, I hope there's less chance of pain. Best of luck.

Comment: Answer of tremendous help, thanks